# Can I control my computer from my Tablet?

Tags: wireless, networking, bluetooth, tablet

I'm wondering if there is an App/something else that can control my computer from any internet point? Like, if I'm at school with my tablet, and I forget to turn of my computer, can I shut down my computer from my tablet.  I also would like a console that I can execute commands from my tablet with.  Please explain answer with GREAT detail, for I just installed ubuntu yesterday for the first time and I have no idea how to do things.

My computer has a 2TB HDD and 12GB or ram. It has wireless networking and such, Bluetooth, and Ubuntu 10.04.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use [TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/) to control your computer from your tablet. If you just want a command line/file access to your computer, you can install [OpenSSH](http://www.openssh.com/) with `sudo apt-get install openssh-server` and connect to it from your tablet using [JuiceSSH](http://juicessh.com) for the command line, and [ES File Explorer](http://www.estrongs.com/) for file access.